# Monitor Log In Multi-User Software

Tags: c#, sql, database

We are currently developing a software in C# that implements audit trail, but we cannot know which user implements the update/insert/delete when it is used by multi-user. my user table looks like this:

```
create table Users(
    userID varchar(20) not null,
    userPass varchar(20) not null,
    userFName varchar(25) not null,
    userLName varchar(25) not null,
    userMName varchar(25) not null,
    secretAnswer varchar(40),
    userStatus int default 0,
    primary key(userID)
)
```

The userStatus checks if the user is logged in, by default it is 0, meaning he/she is not logged in. When he/she logs in, it will be updated to 1, meaning he/she is the current user of the software. So, to check who is logged in, my code is

```
select userID from Users where userStatus = 1
```

Then all the userStatus of all the user will be reset to 0 once he logged out, or the software is closed. But this logic is only applicable on individual user. How can I track the user that implements the update/insert/delete? I'm using C#. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Dustine can't you get at the current user by logging the current yser using the following 
`string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;` this will return the `domain\\username` then all you have to do is split on the return value on `"\\"` if you need a coded example I can post one for you

Comment: i'm not familiar with the process, sir. can you please post a code? it will be a big help for me.

Comment: I posted the code try it on your machine locally and you will see that it will return your userID based on what your username is that you user to long on to your current pc or laptop.. please post any additional questions if you need help. Also if you are supporting the code / application you can do a global search in your project where the logging is being done currently and stub in any necessary code / variable that you need to long this..it's pretty straight forward

Comment: the code returns the name of the machine that i'm using . what if i logged in another account for this machine, it will still return the machine i'm using . is it possible that i can take it from the user accounts present in the database ? anyway, thanks for the code :) this might help .

Comment: I will add code to my answer that will do a Split into a string[] and you can access user by the 2nd element in the array.. if you long in as  a different user it would still show that users name I am assuming that that you know who's account belongs to what user as long as you are not logging in with a service account.. then you will have to do some rethinking on your current process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dustine in your code before you write to the log you can track the current user whom is Invoking the code based on their log in you could do this and it will return the current user you will need to determine where in your code you would like to place it

```
var currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split(
    new [] {"\\"}, 
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
```

here is the same code that you can see Splits the string into the `Domain` and the `User`

```
var currentUser2 = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
var SplitUser = currentUser2.Split(new string[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var domain = SplitUser[0];
var domainUser = SplitUser[1];
```